# How to get the own name of an instance reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, instance

Is it possible to get the name of the reference of an instance which is calling a function, in the function?
In the function called by the reference of the instance, the name of the reference that called the function should be recognized. Is this possible? Thanks.

```
redCar = Car()
blackCar = Car()

redCar.carControl()
blackCar.carControl()


def carControl():

    if trafficJam == True:
        redCar.changeSpeed(500)
        redCar.warningLights(On)

        #is something like the following possible?
        "GetNameOfReferenceWhichCalledTheFunction".changeSpeed(500)
        "GetNameOfReferenceWhichCalledTheFunction".warningLight(On)
```

Comment: How id `Car` defined ? Because if it is a class, your python code is unvalid. And it is unvalid because the method has no parenthesis

Comment: Can you not just do `self.changeSpeed(500)`?

Comment: Seeing your edits, I guess this is unvalid and untested and untried code ? But rather a whish, because `Car` is undefined

Comment: yes its untested and more or less a wish

Comment: At this point it is probably better to follow along with a language tutorial than to ask about each little thing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances don't call functions. You can call the *method of* an instance, which is what you do with e.g. `redCar.carControl()`. Because `carControl` is a method, it needs to be defined inside the class.

But yes, within that method, you can access `redCar` - because it *is passed as an argument* and you *need* a parameter to receive it. By convention, we use the name `self` for this parameter.

Please study the example carefully:

```
traffic_jam = True

class Car:
    def control(self):
        if traffic_jam:
            # The display message will show some debug information that
            # identifies the object. It doesn't have the name `red_car`
            # built into it - it cannot, because you can use multiple names
            # for the same thing - but it is identified uniquely.
            print(self, "slowing down and putting on warning lights")

red_car = Car()
# When this call is made, the `red_car` will be passed to the method,
# which knows it as `self`.
red_car.control()
```

Comment: perfect, I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When using a class, the instance that called the method is accessible using the first parameter, filled automatically, generally called `self`

```
class Car:
    def carControl(self):
        if trafficJam == True:
            self.changeSpeed(500)
            self.warningLights(On)

    def changeSpeed(self, value):
        self.speed = value


redCar = Car()
redCar.carControl()
redCar.changeSpeed(250)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def change_speed(self, speed):
        print(self.name, ": speed =", speed)

    def car_control(self, traffic_jam):
        if traffic_jam:
            self.change_speed(0)
        else:
            self.change_speed(50)


red_car = Car("red")
black_car = Car("black")

red_car.car_control(True)
black_car.car_control(False)
```

Output:

```
red : speed = 0
black : speed = 50
```